# Dio options.contentType vs header "Content-Type"

Tags: rest, http, flutter, dart

I was trying to make a call to a REST service using [the Dio plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/dio), but kept getting `HTTP 400` response code. I thought I was doing everything right by setting the content type and response type options to JSON:

```
Response response = await Dio().get(
    'https://api.example.com/v1/products/$productId',
    queryParameters: {},
    options: Options(
        contentType: ContentType.json,
        responseType: ResponseType.json,
        headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer $MY_API_KEY'}
    ),
);
```

However, it turns out that I needed to add a `Content-Type` header as well:

```
headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer $MY_API_KEY'}, 'Content-Type': 'application/json' };
```

So now I'm confused - what exactly does the `contentType` option do? I thought it was analogous to setting the `Content-Type` header manually?

Comment: In the documentation it states (for `contentType`) `The request Content-Type. The default value is [ContentType.json]` . So maybe you ought to omit it?

Answer (score 10):

I've tried this locally using `dio: ^3.0.10` and it seems that `ContentType.json` is an invalid value for `contentType`.

[image: invalid contentType]

Digging through the [documentation for dio](https://pub.dev/documentation/dio/latest/#request-options), `Headers.jsonContentType` should be used.

[image: valid contentType]